# Cut and paste duplicates from one sheet to another using VB

Tags: excel, vba

I have some data (names) in column A.  There are times where some names will be duplicated.  I am looking for a vb to cut all the duplicated rows and paste to another sheet call duplicates.  Normally when I use the remove duplicate function in excel it just removes all the duplicates and leaves the one unique name.

In my case for example if I have john doe in A2, A3 & A7 I want the vb to cut all 3 rows (A2, A3 & A7) and paste to the other sheet.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?

```
Sub removedup()
Dim x As Integer
Dim unique() As String
ReDim unique(0)
Dim dups() As String
ReDim dups(0)
Dim dupFlag As Boolean
Dim dupCount As Integer
Dim rowcount As Integer
Dim sheet2indexer As Integer

'get array of all unique names
dupFlag = False
x = 1
Do While Sheets(1).Cells(x, 1).Value <> ""
    For y = 0 To UBound(unique)
        If Sheets(1).Cells(x, 1).Value = unique(y) Then
            dupFlag = True
        End If
    Next y
    If dupFlag = False Then
        ReDim Preserve unique(UBound(unique) + 1)
        unique(UBound(unique)) = Sheets(1).Cells(x, 1).Value
    Else
        dupFlag = False
    End If

x = x + 1

Loop

rowcount = x - 1

'unique(1 to unbound(unique)) now contains one of each entry
'check which values are duplicates, and record

dupCount = 0

For y = 1 To UBound(unique)
    x = 1
    Do While Sheets(1).Cells(x, 1).Value <> ""
        If unique(y) = Sheets(1).Cells(x, 1).Value Then
            dupCount = dupCount + 1
        End If
        x = x + 1
    Loop
    If dupCount > 1 Then
        'unique(y) is found more than once
        ReDim Preserve dups(UBound(dups) + 1)
        dups(UBound(dups)) = unique(y)
    End If
        dupCount = 0
Next y

sheet2indexer = 0
'now we have a list of all duplicate entries, time to start moving rows
For z = rowcount To 1 Step -1
    For y = 1 To UBound(dups)
        If Sheets(1).Cells(z, 1).Value = dups(y) Then
            'current row z is a duplicate
            sheet2indexer = sheet2indexer + 1
            Sheets(1).Rows(z).Cut Sheets(2).Rows(sheet2indexer)
            Sheets(1).Rows(z).Delete
        End If
    Next y
Next z


End Sub
```

Comment: yes exactly like that!!!  Thanks a million user3479671.  That saves me a lot of time :)

Comment: No problem at all.  I hope you can learn from it so in the future you can have a go at it yourself.